# Make images fill container that is 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wanting these images to fill the container width, so no white space (or in the example below, no yellow space) is seen.

Because the container width is 100%, I cannot set a percentage width on the image element. If I did I'd end up with tiny images on smaller devices.

What's the solution here? I do not mind re-sizing the images a little to make them fit the container perfectly, but nothing drastic.

http://jsfiddle.net/28cyyb2m/

```
<div class="test">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
    <img src="..">
</div>
```

Comment: Can't quite understand what you're asking. You want the images to fit the container, but not on smaller devices?

Comment: You'll need to use JavaScript to achieve what you're after.

Comment: What you're saying is you want no gaps, and a minimum size for each image? One simple alternative (since you specifically want to target mobile devices) is to use percentages and media querys.

Comment: I want the images to fit the container, without white space at the end of each row. A minimum size of an image would be helpful yeah, if that's how it would be done.

Comment: Unless all your images are the same width, this will be hard to do with CSS alone.  You might want to look at: http://desandro.com/masonry.

Comment: All images are the same width and height.

Comment: @ditto do you mind specifying how many images/row you want?

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2d09tund/

Comment: @roko c. buljan unlimited images.

Comment: @ditto than you'll need JS to calculate the remaining space and divide that space to the images in every current row.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the obvious, how would I even determine a row?

Comment: @ditto see gnack's answer

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan he accepted the media query answer. I can see 1 million lines of media queries in the OPs future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your image to have an evenly divisible width percentage and make the height auto.  For example:

```
img {
    width:25%; /* 4 images across */
    height:auto;
}
```

If 4 images across is too small on mobile, use media queries to change the width to 50% or 100% on mobile.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    img {
        width: 50%; /* 2 images across */
    }
}
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g84yu198/

Comment: I'd have to use a max-width to prevent the width 25% from making the image too large, and with that it causes problems.

Comment: No, you'd just use more break points in your media query.  At larger resolution, make it 20%, or 10%, or whatever you want.  At say 1200px maybe you want 20%, and at 1800px you want 16.666%, etc.

Comment: He wants to be able to keep the image around the same size and fit as many as possible into the width, writing manual CSS media queries for every potential size that he might need is really not the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you're after only with JavaScript.  Here's a jQuery example of how you would do this:

```
$(function() {
    var resizeImages = function() {
        var minimumWidth = 100;
        var containerWidth = $('.test').width();
        var numberPerRow = Math.floor(containerWidth / minimumWidth) - 1;
        var actualWidth = containerWidth / numberPerRow;

        $('.test img').css({width: actualWidth});
    }

    $(window).on('load resize', resizeImages);

});
```

It uses a minimumWidth to stop your images getting too small, and will fit as many as possible into one row without breaking that rule (so your images don't get too big either).

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n05t55bt/1/

Comment: Yes, I think this is what OP is after... I'd just make it `$(window).on('load resize', resizeImages);`

Comment: Using Javascript and window resize functions for something that CSS media queries are specifically designed for seems backwards to me.  Don't get me wrong, I love javascript, but this just seems unnecessary.

Comment: So far no one has shown how to do what the OP has requested using CSS alone - automatically adjust the image sizes to fit as many as possible on the one row without dropping below a certain size. This is because it's not possible, using CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with display options table and table-cell.

```
.gallery {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.gallery .image {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qq8py50j/

Answer (score -1):

This makes the images width 100% fullscreen.

```
body, html, .test {
    display:block;
    background:yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:0;
}
img {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: @Jan exactly. OP missed to explain what he actually wants with those images.